# Help with Nagios check_postgres.pl custom query

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have a postgres function that returns two columns

result, data
(int), (text)

If I run this command from postgres it returns the proper values and if I run it from the linux command line like this:

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_postgres.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u postgres -db monitordb --action=custom_query --critical=1 --query="SELECT * from ops_get_status();"

It also return the proper values - at least it seems to and I don't get any errors.

But when I insert it in the commands.cfg and watch this through the Nagios frontend 
it return (null).

The log file doesn't contain any detailed information for debugging this.  So, what can I do to get to the bottom of this issue - any help greatly appreciated

result

Comment: Have you tried `su`:ing  to the nagios user on the command line? That users environment might be different from your regular shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this same problem.  Removing the semi-colon from the end of the query got it working.

Mail archives reference here:

https://mail.endcrypt.com/pipermail/check_postgres/2011-February/000726.html

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I also got a similar error with a custom query, but it turns out you need to return a column called 'result' and it must be an integer.

For example:

```
check_postgres.pl --action=connection --db=db-name --host=x.x.x.x --dbuser=db-user --action=custom_query --critical=10 --warning=5 --query="SELECT count(id) as result from your-table"
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but try enclosing the query in single quotes. The * might be somehow getting expanded.