# Problem Nagios check_postgres.pl custom query

Tags: plugins, nagios

I have a problem, I launch the query from the local nagios server and I get an invalid format error, can you tell me the reason for this error?

```
/check_postgres.pl  -H lab --p 5432 -db test --action=custom_query \
--query="select max_conn,used,res_for_super,max_conn-used-res_for_super \
res_for_normal from (select count(*) used from pg_stat_activity) t1, (select setting::int res_for_super from pg_settings where name='superuser_reserved_connections') t2, (select setting::int max_conn from pg_settings where name='max_connections') t3;" \
--valtype=string -w 5 -c 10 --timeout 100
```

This is the error that appears

```
POSTGRES_CUSTOM_QUERY UNKNOWN: DB "test" (host:lab) Invalid format returned by custom query | time=0.03s used=15;5;10
```

As you can see it shows me the data but not in nagios readable format. Best regards

Comment: This is Nagios readable format, why do you think it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things here:

1. Your `valtype` is probably `integer` and not `string` (you can omit this parameter in this case, it is `integer` by default)
   Check out https://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#custom_query
2. You need to add `as result` in your SQL query (exactly alias result) and based on fact that you are supposed to get a single integer as reply to the query and by that you specify what column/function/...

```
select count(*) as result from myexample_table
```

Mentioned also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814639/17052885